# Shorting of VCC & GND for short duration of time

Tags: uln2003

I have used [ULN2003A](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjRv_KN2_jlAhUMX30KHXEYAMwQFjAAegQIAhAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Fulq2003a&usg=AOvVaw06VxrI8m7h8eYMppxmhxWC) for my custom board. While checking "continuity" between VCC and GND there is a continuity for a short duration of time(less than a second), it comes at a random time.

I have powered ON a fully assembled board and tested. Everything is working as expected.

In the datasheet, it is mentioned that there are freewheeling diodes for protection. Do these diodes cause that short duration continuity?

Edit:-
I have followed EVM for designing schematic:-
[image]

---

Comment: do you have decoupling capacitors on your board?

Comment: can you explain how you test "continuity" ? that might hint to what you are seeing.

Comment: @james I have used 0.1uf ceramic and 470uf capacitor

Comment: @Navaro I keep the multimeter on continuity mode. I will place one probe on the GND pin and another on the VCC pin

Comment: @MightyBeard007 Hint: a multimeter in continuity mode applies a voltage to its probes and measures the current. What does you 470µF capacitor do, then?

Comment: @MarcusMüller it charges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your  comment : When you use the multimeter in continuity mode it applies a voltage to the circuit. Since you apply the voltage between VCC and Ground, the capacitors which are initially completely discharged provide a short circuit for a very short time. So this will give you the short "beep sound" you are witnessing.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely your decoupling capacitors which allows a small current to pass until charged by the multimeter.

The freewheeling diodes might conduct depending on which probe is connected to ground/vcc, but they should not cause a complete short.